# Load Time Weaving not working in domain object

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I have a scenario where I need to access spring managed beans in my domain object(i.e. object created with **new** operator). I searched a lot and found that it can be done using Load Time Weaving provided by aspectJ. I've done all configurations for the above to the best of my knowledge. I'm new to aspectJ. Following are my code and the configuration files.

**Domain class,**

```
package test.components;

import hibSERVICES.NounHeader.NounHeaderService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

@Configurable
public class TestLoadTimeWeaving {

    @Autowired
    private NounHeaderService nounHeaderService;

    public void hello(){
        nounHeaderService.findByPrimaryKey(0L);
    }

}
```

**Controller,**

package test.controllers;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/testController.do")
public class TestController{

@RequestMapping(params = "todo=onLoad", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public void onLoad(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
TestLoadTimeWeaving testLoadTimeWeaving = new TestLoadTimeWeaving();
testLoadTimeWeaving.hello();
}
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
        http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">



        <context:spring-configured />
        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="test" />
        <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>
        <bean lass="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect" factory-method="aspectOf"/>
```

**aop.xml,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
    "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN"
    "http://www.aspectj.org/dtd/aspectj_1_5_0.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <exclude within="*..*CGLIB*" />
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

I've written **-javaagent:c:\spring-agent-2.5.6.jar as the VM argument**

Using following jars to support LTW and aspectJ,

- aspectjrt-1.5.4.jar
- spring-agent-2.5.6.jar
- spring-aspect.jar
- aspectjWeaver-1.5.4.jar
- spring-2.5.6.jar

All other spring dependencies are working fine, only the dependencies which are injected in the domain objects( i.e. object created with **new** operator) are not working i.e. I'm getting null for those depedencies.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.